# Ler uma linha de console em C#

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, console

> CS1503 Argumento 1: não é possível converter de "grupo de métodos" para "object"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Teste
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("QUal é a sua idade?");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine); // erro nesta linha
            if (age < 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Não é permitido entrada de menores de 16.");
            } else if (age >= 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bem-Vindo!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Estou Utilizando Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funcionar é diferente de estar certo e isto é uma das coisas mais importantes que precisa aprender em desenvolvimento de software.

[image: Funcionar é diferente de estar certo]

Neste caso se alguém digitar algo errado quebrará o programa, assim funciona e está certo:

```
using static System.Console;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        WriteLine("Qual é a sua idade?");
        if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var age)) {
            if (age < 16) WriteLine("Não é permitido entrada de menores de 16.");
            else WriteLine("Bem-Vindo!");
        } else WriteLine("O valor informado é inválido");

    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pIHy2B). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c4DNCs). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/ReadTry.cs).

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkk top o 147

Answer (score 3):

Você pode escrever essa linha da conversão dessa forma:

```
int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Obrigado, int.Parse funcionou!

Answer (score 3):

Só pra deixar registrado, o erro que está dando é porque você se esqueceu de por os `Parenteses ()` no método `Console.ReadLine()`. Se você alterar e usar o `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` Irá funcionar tão bem quanto o `int.Parse()`. Ah e não se esqueça de adicionar o `Console.ReadLine()` no final do programa para que seu programa não feche sem que você possa ver nada. O código consertado var ficar assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Teste
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("QUal é a sua idade?");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // erro nesta linha
            if (age < 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Não é permitido entrada de menores de 16.");
            } else if (age >= 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bem-Vindo!");
            }

           Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```